# Cannot write a proper format function in MS Access query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

When I try to write `Format([my_date_element], "yyyy/mm/dd")` I get an error because of bad syntax.

Comment: What is the exact error message? What date type is my_date_element? What is the full SQL statement?

Comment: Ok, I solved a problem, but thank you Andy, because when I changed the SQL statement everything worked just fine. Then I noticed that in a project view the above expression changed to Format([my_date_element], "rrrr/mm/dd"). It's because in my language (Polish) "year" means "rok" and it appears that I have to use Polish symbols in project view next time when I have MS Access set to Polish.

Answer (score 2):

In the project view of a query you have different symbols depending on the language you use. So e. g. "year" means "rok" in Polish and thus I have to use "r" instead of "y" in Format function.

Comment: Add a note about where the language is set; is this an Access setting or an OS setting?